# insert into new column values generated from trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger which generates an 18 digit code based on the value of several other columns in the table.

`R-MU-WEST-RJS-9697` So basically my last 4 digit code is the `STORE_CODE` based on which I want to compare and insert that 18 digit code against it the column named as `CODE_18DIGIT`

Below is the `select` statement that generates the code

```
SELECT    'R-'
  || CASE
         WHEN INSTR (TRIM (r.state), ' ') > 1
         THEN
                SUBSTR (r.state, 1, 1)
             || SUBSTR (r.state, INSTR (r.state, ' ') + 1, 1)
         ELSE
             UPPER (SUBSTR (r.state, 1, 2))
     END
  || '-'
  || UPPER (SUBSTR (r.zone_name, 1, 4))
  || '-'
  || r.format_code
  || '-'
  || SUBSTR (r.store_code, 1, 4)
FROM tbl_rrsoc_store_info  r
WHERE r.ISACTIVE = 'Y';
```

and the table description of `tbl_rrsoc_store_info` is below

```
Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
RRSOC_ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER         
STORE_CODE                  NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(55)  
STATE                                NVARCHAR2(55)  
CITY                                 NVARCHAR2(55)
CODE_18DIGIT                         NVARCHAR2(18)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  You say you have a trigger but you posted a `select` statement.  That statement would, generally speaking, cause a mutating table exception if it were embedded in a row-level trigger on `tbl_rrsoc_store_info`.  Are you asking how to turn that `select` statement into something that is valid in a trigger?  Or how to backfill the `code_18digit` column in the table?  Or something else?  Why would `code_18digit` be defined as an `nvarchar2(55)` rather than an `nvarchar2(18)` assuming it will always be 18 characters?

Comment: And, just to throw it out, why are you storing that code separately rather than creating it as a computed column or computing it in a view on top of the table?  It seems to just be duplicating data that is already stored in a proper relational format in the same row.

Comment: @JustinCave: so how can we make it as a computated column in a view ?? Also, yes I will change the range to `nvarchar2(18)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecturally, this is not a particularly good design.  You're violating basic rules of normalization by storing redundant data.  It would be much less objectionable to just create a view that computes the code or to add a computed column to the table instead.  But it sounds like you have decided that you want to use the trigger-based solution.

For simplicity, I'd create a function (note that the code you posted references multiple columns that don't exist in the table definition you posted.  My guess is that the columns exist and were omitted from your table definition but maybe you changed the column names in either your query or your table definition and didn't change them in the other).

```
create or replace function make_18digit_code( 
  p_state tbl_rrsoc_store_info.state%type,
  p_zone_name tbl_rrsoc_store_info.zone_name%type, -- Note that your table definition doesn't include this column
  p_format_code tbl_rrsoc_store_info.format_code%type, -- Or this column
  p_store_code tbl_rrsoc_store_info.store_code%type 
)
  return tbl_rrsoc_store_info.code_18digit%type
is
begin
  return 'R-'  || 
         CASE
         WHEN INSTR (TRIM (p_state), ' ') > 1
         THEN
                SUBSTR (p_state, 1, 1)
             || SUBSTR (p_state, INSTR (p_state, ' ') + 1, 1)
         ELSE
             UPPER (SUBSTR (p_state, 1, 2))
     END
  || '-'
  || UPPER (SUBSTR (p_zone_name, 1, 4))
  || '-'
  || p_format_code
  || '-'
  || SUBSTR (p_store_code, 1, 4);
end;
```

Then you can simply call the function in the trigger

```
create or replace trigger trg_generate_code
  before insert or update on tbl_rrsoc_store_info
  for each row
begin
  :new.code_18digit := make_18digit_code( :new.state,
                                          :new.zoe_name,
                                          :new.format_code,
                                          :new.store_code );
end;
```

Comment: getting error as `Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00957: duplicate column name`

Comment: Also Justin, it would be great if those values are inserted in one of the columns I created.. please help in doing that

Comment: @Nad - Did you remove the `code_18digit` column from the table?  The whole point of calculating the value in the view is that you wouldn't have the column in the table.  Back to the questions I tried to ask-- what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your question says you have a trigger.  You haven't posted a valid trigger.  You posted a `select` that would cause errors inside a row-level trigger.  Are you looking for a valid trigger?  For an `update` statement to backfill the new column?  To make the new column a computed value?  Something else?

Comment: Nope, I didn't removed the column. Also, yes looking for a valid trigger that would fill the new column which is `code_18digit`.

Comment: @Nad - OK.  So you don't have a trigger, as stated in your question.  You want a trigger.  You understand that storing redundant, calculated data in a table violates the basic rules of normalization and generally leads to all sorts of downstream problems but you want to do it anyway.  You don't want to have a computed column in the table or to leave the calculation in a view.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I want trigger to be created which generated 18 digit code and insert those code in columns created.!!

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: @Nad - OK.  I've updated your question with what it sounds like you want and given you the trigger code.  It's a poor architectural approach but hopefully you have your reasons

Comment: Thanks Justin, it's just serving my purpose.!!